# parsed-literal with inline highlighting

Tags: restructuredtext

I'm trying to format an environment variable definition with a few variable parameters that I want to highlight. So I'm using a parsed literal block that includes in-line highlighting:

```
.. parsed-literal::

    $ export MYVAL=http://*<user_name>*:*<user_password>*@127.0.0.1:*<port>*/*<resource>*
```

I'm expecting each of the bracketed parameters to be italicized, but instead I'm getting some extra asterisks in the output. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add backslash-escaped whitespace before and after `@127.0.0.1:`, it will work:

```
$ export MYVAL=http://*<user_name>*:*<user_password>*\ @127.0.0.1:\ *<port>*/*<resource>*
```

See http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#character-level-inline-markup.